# Полнота по Тьюрингу

Tags: любой-язык, теория

Как известно, большинство широко используемых языков программирования (особенно императивных) полны по Тьюрингу. А некоторые — даже относительно времени компиляции, как, скажем, С++ с их шаблонами.

А каким образом доказывается/опровергается полнота по Тьюрингу? Само по себе это понятие  выглядит трудно формализуемым.

Comment: ... а прагматически -- берём какой-нибудь простой Тьюринг-полный язык, например, PL/1, и смотрим, что все его конструкции выразимы на языке, который нам интересен.

Comment: (запоздалое дополнение) А лучше BrainFuck, он намного проще.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Формально это надо доказывать это с точки зрения теории [рекурсивных функций](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_function) — язык полон по Тьюрингу тогда и только тогда, когда он позволяет записать каждую вычислимую функцию. На практике для этого обычно достаточно ловко проапеллировать к [тезису Черча].(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church%E2%80%93Turing_thesis)
- См. также «[How to Prove a Programming Language is Turing Complete?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112011/how-to-prove-a-programming-language-is-turing-complete)».

Answer (score 2):

Почему-то мне кажется, что если мы можем реализовать машину Тьюринга на каком-то языке, то это означает, что он тьюринг-полный. Хотя могу ошибаться.